# Using 2 buttons in same ASP.NET MVC Form

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

In general, is it possible to have two different buttons within the same form that post to different controller actions in ASP.NET MVC?

I am essentially trying to have two input (type="button") tags in the same form, but I want them to perform different controller actions.  I would like to do this in a few cases because I think it provides a good aesthetic to be able to click buttons as opposed to hyperlinks.  Is there a way to do this or should I design it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts about handling this in the browser:

- You can use links which are styled to look like buttons. This is easy to do, either with images or by putting the link in a block element with borders.
- You can use two buttons which don't directly submit; they instead call a javascript function that sets the form action before submitting.

Comment: Links don't submit forms. In case they do (through JS) - then where's the difference between 1st and 2nd approach?

Comment: Links can perform a get request, and you could use JavaScript to build the URL. But, you're right - if you need form elements to be submitted, there's no real benefit to links.

Comment: Styling links and buttons to look the same is eventually the direction I went.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 9):

Not really possible without using Javascript.  With Javascript you'd just have to define different click handlers that invoked the proper action.

```
 $(function() {
      $('#button1').click( function() {
          $(form).attr( 'action', '<% Url.Action( "action1" ) %>' )
                 .submit();
          return false; // prevent default submission
      });
      $('#button2').click( function() {
           $(form).attr( 'action', '<% Url.Action( "action2" ) %>' )
                 .submit();
          return false; // prevent default submission
      });
});
```

Comment: Please note that this example is using jQuery... an excellent choice IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is something like OK & Cancel buttons, then have a look at [this post by David Findley](http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2009/05/31/asp-net-mvc-multiple-buttons-in-the-same-form.aspx).

I'm using this method on my Edit view, where I have an Edit button and a Delete button. The delete button only requires the Id of the item. In the code below you can see that I've named my attribute "AcceptFormValueAttribute". This is method good for me, because my Delete [Get] action just shows a message asking for confirmation, so needs the redirect.

```
    [ActionName("Edit")]
    [AcceptFormValue(Name = "Action", Value = "Delete")]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditDelete(int? id)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Delete", new { id = id });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC but with html. The only way I see how you could do this is by modifying the action attribute of the form tag using javascript on submission of the form by checking which button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few ways you could handle this. Assuming you aren't sending data with the button click I'd go with option 3. If data must be included then consider option 1 with some sort of temporary data store (like TempData).

1. One form posts to one controller
   action on submit and the controller
   action checks which button was
   clicked and then dispatches a
   RedirectToAction(). **(Not great)**
2. Multiple forms on one page post to multiple controller actions **(Better)**
3. Inside or outside a form create an `input type="button"` and give it an onclick handler
   that redirects the user to a controller action **(Best)**

Comment: Redirecting won't maintain the data being passed.  You'd have to store the data in TempData to retain it.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this, but given the ID of the clicked button does get sent VIA http POST, you could probably do something like:

```
<input type="submit" name="GO" ID="GO" value="GO BUTTON" />
<input type="submit" name="STOP" ID="STOP" value="STOP BUTTON" />
```

Then on the mvc end, just have two methods, one with a go parameter, one with a stop parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**Method #1**

How about using two different forms wrapping the buttons, then using CSS to position one of them so that it appears (visually) to be inside the "main" form?

A really quick example:

```
<fieldset id="CombinedForm">

<form ... action="Method1">
  ...form stuff here...
  <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="Do something">
</form>

<form ... action="Method2">
  ...form stuff here...
  <input id="Button2" type="submit" value="Do something else">
</form>

</fieldset>
```

...Then using CSS as follows:

```
#CombinedForm {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 2em; /* leave space for buttons */
}

#Button1, #Button2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#Button1 {
  left: 0;
}

#Button2 {
  right: 0;
}
```

The result should be that you have a `fieldset` or `div` which looks like a form, having two actual HTML forms inside it, and two buttons which are positioned within the parent box, yet submitting to different locations.

**Method #2**

Another method occurs: have both buttons in the same form, pointing to one controller action, that then decides (based on the value of the button clicked) which action to redirect to.

Comment: #1 - most likely those buttons needs to submit the same data, so - it won't work. #2 just feels awkward - doesn't it? :)

Comment: @Amis - it all feels a bit awkward :p  But if they're submitting the same data, and the only difference is what to do with it, then to me that sounds like it's the same method with a different switch. TBH, this is more than likely going to be used for OK/Cancel buttons, where cancel doesn't need to submit any data at all.

Answer (score 0):

Its not Javascript required...

how about this

> public ActionResult DoSomething()
>   {
>        // Some business logic
>        TempData["PostedFormValues"] = Request.Form;
>        if (Request.Form("ButtonA") != null)
>        {
>           return RedirectToAction("ActionA", RouteData.Values);
>        }
>        return RedirectToAction("ActionB", RouteData.Values);
>   }

Answer (score 0):

I think that I can suggest more simple one.

For example you have two buttons : ButtonA,ButtonB  and want to perform different 
action on each one.
Simplest solution is : just use BeginForm statement:

```
@using ( Html.BeginForm("ButtonA" , "Home") )
{
        <input type="submit" value="ButtonA"/>
}

@using ( Html.BeginForm("ButtonB" , "Home") )
{
        <input type="submit" value="ButtonB" />
}
```

You must also declare ButtonA,ButtonB actions in your Home controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ButtonA()
{ . . . }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ButtonB()
{ . . . }
```